# Spec Changes - How to Refactor My JavaScript Logic?

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, youtube-api

This is probably quite straight-forward but at the moment I can't think of a good way to do this (having a complete brain fart).

I currently have a script that fetches videos from a youtube channel and displays the current video and 3 thumbnails underneath with a left and right arrow to navigate to the previous or next three thumbs to choose another video to watch.

The spec just changed (again) and now it needs to move just one to the left or right when an arrow is clicked instead of 3.

i.e. :

**Current Logic:**

```
<<    [1] [2] [3]  >>  **click right** << [4] [5] [6] >>
```

**Desired Logic**

```
<<    [1] [2] [3]  >>  **click right** << [2] [3] [4] >>
```

**Code:**

```
var youtube = 
{
    author    : "XXXXXXX",
    pageNr    : 0,
    pageSize  : 3,
    pageCount : 1,
    videos    : [],
    gets      : function()
    {
        var _this = this;
        var url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=" + this.author + "&start-index=" + (this.pageNr * this.pageSize + 1) + "&max-results=" + this.pageSize + "&v=2&orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&fields=openSearch:totalResults,entry(id,title,media:group(media:thumbnail,yt:videoid),yt:statistics)";
        $.getJSON(url + "&callback=?",
        function(response)
        {
            _this.show(response.feed.entry);
        });
    },
    start     : function()
    {
        var _this = this;
        var url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=" + this.author + "&start-index=" + (this.pageNr * this.pageSize + 1) + "&max-results=" + this.pageSize + "&v=2&orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&fields=openSearch:totalResults,entry(id,title,media:group(media:thumbnail,yt:videoid),yt:statistics)";
        $.getJSON(url + "&callback=?",
        function(response)
        {
            _this.pageCount = Math.floor(response.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t / 3);
            _this.show(response.feed.entry);
            $(".video-thumb").eq(0).click();
        });
    },
    next      : function()
    {
        if(this.pageNr >= this.pageCount){ return; }
        this.pageNr++;

        $(".video-thumb-picture-wrapper,#slider TD").removeClass("selected");

        this.gets();
    },
    prev      : function ()
    {
        if(this.pageNr <= 0){ return; }
        this.pageNr--;

        $(".video-thumb-picture-wrapper,#slider TD").removeClass("selected");

        this.gets();
    },
    show      : function(videos)
    {
        var _this = this;
        _this.videos = [];
        $(videos).each(function(index,video)
        {
            _this.videos.push(
            {
                id         : video.media$group.yt$videoid.$t,
                title      : video.title.$t,
            viewCount  : (video.yt$statistics && video.yt$statistics.viewCount ? video.yt$statistics.viewCount : 0),
            thumbnails : video.media$group.media$thumbnail
        });
    });

    $(".video-thumb-picture").each(function(index,div)
    {
        var video = index < _this.videos.length ? _this.videos[index] : { id : "", title : "", viewCount : 0, thumbnails : [{ url : "" }]  };
        $(div)
        .css("background-image","url('" + video.thumbnails[0].url + "')")
        .parent().next().html(video.title)
        .parent().css("visibility",(index < _this.videos.length) ? "visible" : "hidden");
    });
}
};

var appId = '';
window.fbAsyncInit = function()
{
    FB.init(
    {
        appId  : appId,
        status : true,
        cookie : true,
        xfbml  : true
    });

    FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
};

$(function()
{
        $(".arrow-left").click(function()
    {
        youtube.prev();
    });
    $(".arrow-right").click(function()
    {
        youtube.next();
    });
    youtube.start();

    $("#div-share").unbind('click').click(function()
    {
        FB.ui(
        {
        method : 'feed',
        name   : '',
        link   : ''
        });
    });

    $(".video-thumb").click(function()
    {
        var div = $(this);
        if(div.css("visibility") == "hidden"){ return; }

        $(".video-thumb-picture-wrapper,#slider TD").removeClass("selected");
        div.children().first().addClass("selected").parent().parent().addClass("selected");

        var videoNr = parseInt(div.attr("videonr"));

        var video = youtube.videos[videoNr];
        var html = '<object id="div-video" style="height: 270px; width: 425px" width="425">';
        html += '<param name="play" value="true">';
        html += '<param name="wmode" value="transparent">';
        html += '<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/' + video.id + '?autohide=1&autoplay=1&fs=1&feature=player_embedded" />';
        html += '<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />';
        html += '<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />';
        html += '<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/' + video.id + '?autohide=1&autoplay=0&fs=1&feature=player_embedded" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="425" height="270" wmode="transparent"></embed>';
        html += '</object>';
        $("#div-video").html(html);

        $("#div-video-title").html(video.title);
        $("#b-video-views").html(video.viewCount);

        $("#div-like").html('<fb:like href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + video.id + '" show_faces="false" width="350"></fb:like>');
        FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('div-like'));

        $("#div-share").unbind('click').click(function()
        {
                FB.ui(
            {
                method : 'feed',
                name   : video.title,
                link   : ''
            });
        });
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In gets() and start():

```
"&start-index=" + (this.pageNr + 1)
```

In start():

```
_this.pageCount = (response.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t > _this.pageSize) ?
  (response.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t - _this.pageSize) : (0);
```

Like aepheus mentions, I'd probably rename pageNr to curIndex (or something like) at this point.

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you want the next to be a single, not a page. In that case you would probably want to keep track of the current index and increment it. You could do this by some math with the page size and start page, but it would be much simpler to just track the current index.

```
this.curIndex = 1;
..."&start-index=" + (++this.curIndex)...
```

also, you would only want to change start page when curIndex is a multiple of page size.

Comment: The page size will always be 3 but I don't want 3 new thumbs whenever I click either of the arrows for more thumbs, just one new thumb depending obviously on what was clicked.

I'm leaving work just now but will try and give it a bash with your idea tomorrow.

Thanks.

Comment: thanks for your help, InsDel's answer did the trick perfectly though.